# Ruby on Rails, delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using this [gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) for my application. I cannot find parameters that I need.I have two functions in my controller: create and analyse.
I want to run an `analyse-method` after 5 min when a create-method was called
or
I have one more function in a model: process
I want to run an `anylse-method`(from contoller) after 5 min when a process-method was called.

I have found smt like this:

```
handle_asynchronously :in_the_future, :run_at => Proc.new { 5.minutes.from_now }
```

but it does not say after wich function it should be called.

**edit:**
I attempted to delay my job and it seemed to save everything, the problem is that after 1 min it did not run a `perform_analysis` method.
What can be the problem?

model:

```
after_create :process_name, :perform_analysis

 def perform_analysis
   list=Analysis.do_picture_analyse
   update_image_url(list)
    
  end
 handle_asynchronously :perform_analysis, :run_at => Proc.new { 1.minutes.from_now }
```

> SQL (8.3ms)  INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("attempts", "created_at", "failed_at", "handler", "last_error", "locked_at", "locked_by", "priority", "queue", "run_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["attempts", 0], ["created_at", Sat, 16 Mar 2013 14:30:19 UTC +00:00], ["failed_at", nil], ["handler", "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject: !ruby/ActiveRecord:Arraydb\n  attributes:\n    id: 45\n    arraydb_file_name: ND2_CD8_133A.CEL\n    arraydb_content_type: !binary |-\n      YXBwbGljYXRpb24vb2N0ZXQtc3RyZWFt\n    arraydb_file_size: 12110237\n    defined: 'yes'\n    patient: ND\n    tissue: CD8\n    stimulus: \n    chip_image: \n    chip_info: \n    user_id: \n    hist: \n    hist_RMA: \n    created_at: 2013-03-16 14:30:17.698742003 Z\n    updated_at: 2013-03-16 14:30:19.297934640 Z\nmethod_name: :perform_analysis_without_delay\nargs: []\n"], ["last_error", nil], ["locked_at", nil], ["locked_by", nil], ["priority", 0], ["queue", nil], ["run_at", Sat, 16 Mar 2013 14:31:19 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 16 Mar 2013 14:30:19 UTC +00:00]]

Thanks in advance

Comment: The symbol :in_the_future should be replaced with your own function symbol, e.g., :process.

Comment: but it still doesnt contain a parameter after which method (create) it should wait 5 min

Comment: You need to call the asynch method from create. Our you can pass the proc to delay() and omit the handle_asynchronously. The method isn't going to call itself, you still need to tell delayed_job to do something.

Comment: @DaveNewton asynch method? sorry, I am pretty new to ruby on rails. So, if I use as suggested below, I still need to tell delayed_job to call the function? But why do I need a time limitation then?

Comment: Are you running at least 1 delayed job worker?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. I thought those parameters/codes that I have in my question are sufficient to run method after 5 minutes. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Katja Yes, and the delayed_job documentation discusses all this. You need to have either `rake jobs:work` or something under `daemons` running. See [the docs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs). You set a time in order to tell the job when to run. If you just want it to run asynchronously you don't need to specify `run_at` at all.

Comment: @DaveNewton where should I paste "RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start" then? in script/delayed_job?

Comment: @Katja Pasting a script command into the script itself doesn't make sense. And IMO you shouldn't be doing *anything* in production at this point. You should run `rake jobs:work` for now, unless you've specifically added the `daemons` gem. Please consider taking a step back to figure out what you're actually doing.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with rake jobs:work but I would like to have it automatically without typing extra in the command line. And it is possible with daemons gem, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you can use the daemons gem and a script to help you run your jobs automatically in your local development environment.  But once you know your jobs run I dont see much reason to make them continue running. Then, when you setup your app in production, if you use a service like Heroku, thats when you setup a [Delayed Job worker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job) which will handle executing all your delayed jobs in the background.

Comment: I am using an institute local server for that. And I do not need a development environment. My situation is following: The user logs in in my web-page, uploads some files(create method is invoked). In 5 min after the create method was called the files have to be on there way to be analyzed(perform_analysis method). That is why rake jobs:work doesn't suit me and as I understood once the jobs started they will continue run? I do not need this. I need just some methods run in 5 min after create method.Is it possible to do in production? All this seems too much complicated for such an easy task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callback to trigger the method.  This will trigger the method `:in_the_future` to be queued up in the as a delayed job to run 5 min after the create action is complete.

```
after_create :in_the_future
```

Comment: I edited my question. Your method seems to work, but the function was not called after 1 min

Comment: @Katja Why would it be? Your delay is five minutes. But you're not running a job worker, so there's no reason it'd run at all.